# How can I create a tab in MatLab GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tabs

I am sorry for asking the same questions which has been asked before. But the thing is I am not in matlab for a long and especially during trying to build a GUI I am crossing some problems which looks like complicated when l compare which C#.

Now I am using Matlab 7.12.0(R2011a) and I want to know the possibility to add tab in my GUI to make it more clear.

I am appreciate for answers which could give me an idea to figure out.
Thanks.

Comment: [uitabpanel at fileexchange: click me!](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11546-uitabpanel)

Answer (score 0):

You can create tabs using uipanels where you toggle the visibility to reproduce the tab like behaviou, there are a few utilisties on the Matlab FEX.

To do this you need to be happy with creating GUI's using code only (no guide).

If you do want an easy interactive way of creating a GUI with tabs then I have my own [commercial GUI toolbox](https://sites.google.com/site/matpihome/matlab-gui-framework) that creates very nice tabs.

Comment: That looks so useful. Thanks for sharing. l will look with the details now :)